# PHP - How to extract achor href of specified linked image?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, xpath, extract

How would i extract anchor href of given HTML, based on image src?

Example:

```
<a href="http://idontneedthis.com"><img src="path/to/image/1.gif" /></a>
<a href="http://iwantthis.com"><img src="path/to/image/2.gif" /></a>
<a href="http://idontneedthisagain.com"><img src="path/to/image/3.gif" /></a>
```

In this case i would need to get link of linked image with src of `2.gif`. That would be anchor that has href `http://iwantthis.com`

Comment: No, I want value of href if i know value of img src.

Comment: Check out the second answer, the one that uses `DOMDocument`. That should do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can utilize [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and **XPath** to extract those @href values.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
    <a href="http://idontneedthis.com"><img src="path/to/image/1.gif" /></a>
    <a href="http://iwantthis.com"><img src="path/to/image/2.gif" /></a>
    <a href="http://idontneedthisagain.com"><img src="path/to/image/3.gif" /></a>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[img[contains(@src, "2.gif")]]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
   echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

**Output**

```
http://iwantthis.com
```

Comment: The OP did include the xpath tag in addition to regex, and he didn't specifically say it had to be with regex.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon, updated I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp to solve this kind of problem is a bad idea and will likely lead in unmaintainable and unreliable code. Better us an HTML parser.

If you still want to use a regex, you can try:

```
preg_match_all('%href="(.*?)".*?src="path/to/image/2\.gif"%i', $html, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$href = $match[1][0];
echo $href ;
```

---

**Output:**

```
http://iwantthis.com
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting but this is not what I need. I only know the value of img src and based  on that I should get href value.

Comment: so, you need the opposite, I'll update the code.